# Sending Duplex Message on Silverlight Application Exit

Tags: wcf, silverlight, polling, duplex

I have fully working duplex messaging solution for Silverlight application. Now I would like to add one feature to it. When user leaves the application I want to notify the server about that by sending the last message before exit.

I have tried to send duplex message during Application Exit event, but `DuplexServiceClient` is already in `CommunicationState.Faulted` state.

I've also tried to establish new connection and send the message. Everything seemed to be okay on the client side, but no message has been send at all. I checked that twice by using Fiddler.

```
App.Current.Exit += (s, e) =>
{
    var dsc = new DuplexServiceClient(_binding, new EndpointAddress("../Services/MyService.svc"));
    dsc.SendToServiceAsync(new UserLeave());
};
```

Crucial thing is, that I need to notify the server immediately after user leaves the application, so timeouts or similar workarounds are not good enough for me in this situation.

Does anybody have a working solution?

Comment: Perhaps a connection with JavaScript and in the beforeunload event?

Comment: I have already tried that. Calling `ScriptableMember` method from JavaScript in the `window.onbeforeunload` event handler. It works exactly the same as I would call it during Application Exit event.

Comment: I read somewhere that your second method doesn't work because the server must handle the contract on entry which cannot be done because the client is gone. Have you tried sending the last call with a newly created wcfclient to a method like this: `[ServiceContract]
interface IMyContract
{
   [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
   void Bye()
}`

Comment: Is UserLeave() a oneway operation?

Answer (score 1):

I found similar topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4148472/426290) in SO. Aliostad's answer made me think about this once more. You can never be sure you will get the signal from client that he's leaving. So I ended up with *timeout* solution.